# decompression gzip data with curl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I added `curl_easy_setopt(client, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");` to my code.

I expected curl to cause the server to send compressed data AND to decompress it.

Actually i see in HTTP header that the data is compressed (Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip), but curl doesn't decompress it for me.

Is there an additional command I should use for this?

Answer (score 17):

*Note that this option has been renamed to [`CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTACCEPTENCODING).*

As stated by the documentation:

> Sets the contents of the Accept-Encoding: header sent in a HTTP request, and enables decoding of a response when a Content-Encoding: header is received.

So it does decode (i.e decompress) the response. Three encoding are supported: `"identity"` (does nothing), `"zlib"` and `"gzip"`. Alternatively you can pass an empty string which creates an `Accept-Encoding:` header containing all supported encodings.

At last, [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) is handy to test it out as it contains a dedicated endpoint that returns gzip content. Here's an example:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int
main(void)
{
  CURLcode rc;
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://httpbin.org/gzip");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

  rc = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

  return (int) rc;
}
```

It sends:

```
GET /gzip HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

And gets as response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
...
```

And a JSON response (thus decompressed) is written on stdout.

Answer (score -4):

c++ CURL library does not compress/decompress your data. you must do it yourself.

```
        CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

        struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Encoding: gzip");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, zipped_data.data() );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, zipped_data.size() );
```

Comment: Wrong for downloads (as the previous comment explains), correct for uploads (as HTTP doesn't compress uploads).

Comment: If you use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to specify the Accept-Encoding header, libcurl will not do any compressioin/decompression. But if you use CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING libcurl will do everything for you. See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html