# Libcurl receives encrypted data from 538

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, https, libcurl

I am using libcurl to get some data online. Specifically, I want to keep updated on the information here

https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/pollster-ratings/?ex_cid=irpromo

for research purposes. However, when I use libcurl to pull that data, the result looks encrypted:

‹      ì½ÛVãÈºïy¿ŸÂ5Ö{‰l…ÎÊšUk@f’   df‘7:„m-¹t ÌÞ=F¿F?

It works okay with other https sites so can you tell me why is it not working here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: GZipped I bet see [decompression gzip data with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781856/decompression-gzip-data-with-curl)

Comment: Seems like that's correct, but for some reason, I get an error: Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands identity content encodings. Also, I am not sure if this is related, but it seems they banned my IP address although I can see their website.